# Compile Telegram source code error

Tags: gcc, cygwin, row, telegram, cc

When I compile telegram source code with Cygwin and NDK, get this error :

```
D:/TMessagesProj/jni/./libyuv/source/row_gcc.cc: In function 'void libyuv::I422AlphaToARGBRow_SSSE3(const uint8*, const uint8*, const uint8*, const uint8*, uint8*, const libyuv::YuvConstants*, int)':
D:/TMessagesProj/jni/./libyuv/source/row_gcc.cc:1803:4: error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints
   );
    ^
make: *** [D:/TMessagesProj/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.22/./libyuv/source/row_gcc.o] Error 1
```

[Error screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4DcKGJqEibrSW5ZQy1hdXhUMms)

And

[row_gcc.cc File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4DcKGJqEibrMWxveFpMcVM4VkE)

---

Edit: Code brought in from google drive file:

```
void OMITFP I422AlphaToARGBRow_SSSE3(const uint8* y_buf,
                                     const uint8* u_buf,
                                     const uint8* v_buf,
                                     const uint8* a_buf,
                                     uint8* dst_argb,
                                     const struct YuvConstants* yuvconstants,
                                     int width) {
  asm volatile (
    YUVTORGB_SETUP(yuvconstants)
    "sub       %[u_buf],%[v_buf]               \n"
    LABELALIGN
  "1:                                          \n"
    READYUVA422
    YUVTORGB(yuvconstants)
    STOREARGB
    "subl      $0x8,%[width]                   \n"
    "jg        1b                              \n"
  : [y_buf]"+r"(y_buf),    // %[y_buf]
    [u_buf]"+r"(u_buf),    // %[u_buf]
    [v_buf]"+r"(v_buf),    // %[v_buf]
    [a_buf]"+r"(a_buf),    // %[a_buf]
    [dst_argb]"+r"(dst_argb),  // %[dst_argb]
#if defined(__i386__) && defined(__pic__)
    [width]"+m"(width)     // %[width]
#else
    [width]"+rm"(width)    // %[width]
#endif
  : [yuvconstants]"r"(yuvconstants)  // %[yuvconstants]
  : "memory", "cc", NACL_R14 YUVTORGB_REGS
    "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5"
  );
}
```

Comment: At a guess, this code is intended to be compiled for 64bit, and you are compiling it 32bit.  32bit has have fewer registers than 64bit, and you are running out.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure what has caused this question to bubble back up to the top, but since it has, I'm going to propose my comment as an answer:*

At a guess, this code is intended to be compiled for 64bit, and you are compiling it 32bit. Since 32bit has fewer registers than 64bit, you are running out.  Since the compiler cannot provide that many registers, your 'constraints' are impossible to satisfy, thus the error.